# I am trying to store a music album using JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

So here is what I have. What I need is 2 albums, 4 song each at least. 
Albums should include: name of album, name of artist, year released.
Song information should include: Song Title, Playtime

Songs should be represented as an ARRAY of OBJECTS.

So far these are my albums in code. I think this is incorrect but I am not sure how to fix it. When I run it through a JSON checker, it gives me errors

```
album1 = { 
 "title" : "The Avairy”,
 "artist" : "Galantis”,
 "year_released" : 2017,
 “songs”:[{
    "song1” : "Hey Alligator”,
    "songtime1” : 197,
    “song2” : “True Feeling”,
    “songtime2”: 214,
    “song3” : “Written in the scars”
    “songtime3” : 194,
    “song4” : “No Money”
    “songtime4” : 185;
    }]
}

album2 = {
    "title" : “Kolony”,
    "artist" : “Steve Aoki”,
    "year_released" : 2017,
    “songs”:[
        "song1” : “Lit”,
        "songtime1” : 150,
        “song2” : “Without you”,
        “songtime2”: 207,
        “song3” : “Been Ballin”
        “songtime3” : 180,
        “song4” : “How Else”
        “songtime4” : 152;
    ]
}
```

Comment: What Are the errors? I see that you are using the wrong type of quote.

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 1:
album1 = { "title":


this is the error I get off the bat

Comment: As above, incorrect quotes, and your song property is an array containing a single object in the 1st album, and a syntax error in the second

Comment: The full error should indicate whats wrong

Comment: Im confused now. So the song names should be the ones placed into the array?

Comment: He is saying that in `album1` songs is an array of objects, where `album2` it is an invalid array and should be an object

Comment: ok i see that now.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ggnusfxd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have various problems with your JSON format:

- there should be no semicolons
- there are missing commas in the objects
- you had some strange double quotes (not regular `"`)

You can validate your json using for example https://jsonlint.com/.

```js
{
 "title": "The Avairy",
 "artist": "Galantis",
 "year_released": 2017,
 "songs": [{
  "song1": "Hey Alligator",
  "songtime1": 197,
  "song2": "True Feeling",
  "songtime2": 214,
  "song3": "Written in the scars",
  "songtime3": 194,
  "song4": "No Money",
  "songtime4": 185
 }]
}

{
 "title": "Kolony",
 "artist": "Steve Aoki",
 "year_released": 2017,
 "songs": [{
  "song1": "Lit",
  "songtime1": 150,
  "song2": "Without you",
  "songtime2": 207,
  "song3": "Been Ballin",
  "songtime3": 180,
  "song4": "How Else",
  "songtime4": 152
 }]
}
```

BTW i find this way of modelling album data quite strange. Why not something like this:

```js
[{
 "title": "The Avairy",
 "artist": "Galantis",
 "year_released": 2017,
 "songs": [{
   "title": "Hey Alligator",
   "length": 197
  },
  {
   "title": "True Feeling",
   "length": 214
  },
  {
   "title": "Written in the scars",
   "length": 194
  },
  {
   "title": "No Money",
   "length": 185
  }
 ]
}, {
 "title": "Kolony",
 "artist": "Steve Aoki",
 "year_released": 2017,
 "songs": [{
   "title": "Lit",
   "length": 150
  },
  {
   "title": "Without you",
   "length": 207
  },
  {
   "title": "Been Ballin",
   "length": 180
  },
  {
   "title": "How Else",
   "length": 152
  }
 ]
}]
```

Comment: Well we all start somewhere. Looking at it this way makes more sense than the way I had it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use **"** instead of **“** or **”** everywhere in JSON unless it's inside string like that:

```
json = {
    "title": "Title is “Without you”",
    "artist": "“Steve Aoki”"
};
```

Also in album2 you have "songs" declared as array but you are using it like an object. You have also semicolons inside json which is wrong and missing semicolon after variable declaration and missing comas. Correct code should look like that (I'm giving only album1, do album2 yourself to learn something):

```
album1 = { 
 "title" : "The Avairy",
 "artist" : "Galantis",
 "year_released" : 2017,
 "songs":[{
    "song1" : "Hey Alligator",
    "songtime1" : 197,
    "song2" : "True Feeling",
    "songtime2": 214,
    "song3" : "Written in the scars",
    "songtime3" : 194,
    "song4" : "No Money",
    "songtime4" : 185
    }]
};
```

If you want to be a programmer you need to be very precised. You won't write even simple function with so many syntax errors.

Comment: in this case the album name is kolony. so should it look like this?

json = {
    "title": "Title is “Kolony”",
    "artist": "“Steve Aoki”",
    "year": 2017
};

Comment: This was just an example. Don't take everything explicitly :)

Answer (score 0):

An array of objects suggests more than one. You want this structure instead:

```
{
  "title" : "Kolony",
  "artist" : "Steve Aoki",
  "year_released" : 2017,
  "songs":[
    { 
      "song" : "Lit",
      "songtime" : 150
    },
    { 
      "song" : "Without you",
      "songtime" : 270
    },
    { 
      "song" : "Been Ballin",
      "songtime" : 180
    },
    { 
      "song" : "How Else",
      "songtime" : 152
    }
  ]
}
```

I also noticed semi-colons that shouldn't be there and mixed up quotes. And you need to always use " and not “ or ”.